# Lie algebra where bracket is a morphism of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

Since a Lie algebra is also a vector space, we can see that a Lie algebra has variety structure.

Is the bracket a morphism of varieties, and if it isn't always the case, is there a name for a structure that does have that property?

Motivation:

- If a variety is also a group, where the multiplication and inverse are morphisms of varieties, we have an algebraic group.
- If a variety is also a Lie algebra, where the Lie
  bracket is a morphism of varieties. **What do we call this?**

Comment: Yes, the Lie bracket is bilinear, hence is a morphism $V \times V \rightarrow V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nefertiti said, in an arbitrary finite-dimensional algebra, the bilinear map is a morphism of varieties. Indeed in a basis, the bracket takes the form
$$(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n)\mapsto (z_1,\dots,z_n)$$
$$z_k=\sum_{(i,j)}a_{i,j,k}x_iy_j,$$
where $a_{i,j,k}$ are the structure constants. So each coordinate $z_k$ is indeed polynomial in the variables $(x_1,\dots,y_n)$.